# When I change activity to fragment, I want to modify String array resource ID error

Tags: android-activity, fragment

When I change activity to fragment, I have a 'thread exiting with uncaught exception' error. but, I can't solve the problem. help me plz.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GiFiP.png)

this is the error message.

and this is the java code

```
    int resId = getResources().getIdentifier("Data_" + data, "array", getActivity().getPackageName());
    String[] arData = getResources().getStringArray(resId);

    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
    txtTitle.setText(String.valueOf(arData[0]));

    ImageView image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
    image.setImageResource(getResources().getIdentifier("image_" + getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("Data"), "drawable", getActivity().getPackageName()));
//  image.setImageResource(getResources().getIdentifier("image_" + getArguments().getString("Data"), "drawable", getActivity().getPackageName()));

    TextView txtTitle2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle2);
    txtTitle2.setText(String.valueOf(arData[1]));
    txtTitle2.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

    TextView txtContent = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtContent);
    txtContent.setText(String.valueOf(arData[2]));
    txtContent.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```